# Assignment operator in reference in C++

Tags: c++

> ```
> int value1{ 5 };
> int value2{ 6 };
>
> int &ref{ value1 }; // okay, ref is now an alias for value1
> ref = value2; // assigns 6 (the value of value2) to value1 -- does NOT change the reference!
> ```
>
> Note that the second statement may not do what you might expect! Instead of changing `ref` to reference variable `value2`, it assigns the *value* of `value2` to `value1`.

Why is the value of `ref` not changing? If it is an alias of `value1`, here `value1` is changing, then why doesn't `ref` change?

Comment: Because it's what the C++ spec says.

Comment: References cannot be re-seated (changed to refer to something else after initialization). That's just how the language works.

Comment: You are confusing variable *names* with variable *values.* (And it doesn't help that someone named the variables "value1" and "value2".)

Answer (score 1):

A reference is just an *alias*.  Once a reference has been set to refer to something, it can't be changed to refer to something else.  You can logically replace the reference with the thing it is referring to, to understand what operations on the reference are actually doing.

Since `ref` is a reference (alias) to `value1`, then `ref = value2;` is *identical* to doing `value1 = value2;`  The assignment is modifying the thing that `ref` *refers to* (`value1`), it is not modifying `ref` itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the value of ref is not changing

Because that is the way the language has been designed. It is not possible to change what a reference is bound to. That is a fundamental feature of what references are.

All operations that are syntactically performed on a reference variable are operations on the referred object.